# accumulation of value in Graphite

Tags: graphite

I send one message each time a user connect to my site.

With this format:

```
"user_login 1 13xxxxxxx"  (key value timestamp)
```

My problem is Graphite give me a graph with only a line with the value "1", each minute.
I send a random number of messages each minutes (between 6 and 60), but I think Graphite limits to the first (or last?) message, to display a value.

How to do to have an sum of each message, each minute ?

Answer (score 11):

You could also try carbon aggregation service so that metrics are aggregated when they are collected instead of in the Graphite UI. See http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf for aggregation rule configuration. Note that you need to send the metrics to carbon aggregation service port that is running in different port than the normal carbon collector port.

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in running statsd or statsite on your graphite server. That software will aggregate all statistics per a configurable time period, and write the result out to graphite.

Take a look at github.com/etsy/statsd (in node.js) and github.com/kiip/statsite (python clone). Etsy's statsd contains a few code examples on how to use it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Kind of annoying to have another service running, but it's a little service.

Comment: And I actually used the C (more recent) version of statsite: https://github.com/armon/statsite .  The only annoying thing was that I had to change the default "sink" file to drop the "statsite.counts." prefix that statsite prepends before whatever stats you send it by default.

Answer (score 3):

use sumSeries *target=sumSeries(graphite.counterName)* or summarize function if you want to sum over more than one minute

Answer (score 3):

Jari is correct, carbon-aggregator was written specifically for this.

Make sure you use a sum function in aggregation-rules.conf, such as this:

```
bpu.<cluster>.<account>.<metric>_sum (1) = sum bpu.<cluster>.<account>.<metric>_sum
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hitcount(seriesList, intervalString, alignToInterval=False)
```

http://code.hootsuite.com/accurate-counting-with-graphite-and-statsd/

http://obfuscurity.com/2012/04/Unhelpful-Graphite-Tip-1

http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.hitcount

Answer (score 1):

This may also be how your data is aggregated per metric, it defaults to averages which may not be what you expects. See also [Tracking metrics using StatsD (via etsy) and Graphite, graphite graph doesn't seem to be graphing all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099197/tracking-metrics-using-statsd-via-etsy-and-graphite-graphite-graph-doesnt-se).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cumulative function](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.cumulative) on your series.

> By default, when a graph is drawn, and the width of the graph in
>   pixels is smaller than the number of datapoints to be graphed,
>   Graphite averages the value at each pixel. The cumulative() function
>   changes the consolidation function to sum from average.

Answer (score 1):

by default, graphite only stores the *last* value sent for any incoming metric in the minimum retention granularity (*not* the mean value).  if you want aggregates, the common solution is to use [statsd](http://statsd.readthedocs.org/en/v3.1/).

however, you can also use carbon-aggregator. just be sure you are sending your metrics to the aggregator line port, then update aggregation-rules.conf with a rule like this:

```
user_login (10) = sum user_login$
```

note: this assumes your minimum retention period is still 10 seconds (the default)  you can confirm that by looking in storage-schemas.conf

for a longer explanation, see: [Why use statsd when graphite's Carbon aggregator can do the same job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697553/why-use-statsd-when-graphites-carbon-aggregator-can-do-the-same-job)