# Error with aggregation in graphite

Tags: javascript, graphite

I am trying graphite for the first time. I want to understand why the aggregated graph in graphite is showing 1/60th of the value through carbon and 1/10th of the value I enter through statsd. How do I solve this if it can be done? I am sending this data: echo "try:1|c\n" | nc -u localhost 8125" and then adding the functions sum and integral in the UI of graphite. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The 1/10th value problem is solved by stats_counts bucket.Refer this : [Tracking metrics using StatsD (via etsy) and Graphite, graphite graph doesn't seem to be graphing all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099197/tracking-metrics-using-statsd-via-etsy-and-graphite-graphite-graph-doesnt-se)
The other problem of data value not being accurate is because statsd was sending data at 10s. Just change flushInterval of statsd to 60s and it works fine.