# Why use statsd when graphite's Carbon aggregator can do the same job?

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd

I have been exploring the Graphite graphing tool for showing metrics from multiple servers, and it seems that the 'recommended' way is to send all metrics data to StatsD first. StatsD aggregates the data and sends it to graphite (or rather, Carbon).

In my case, I want to do simple aggregations like sum and average on metrics across servers and plot that in graphite. Graphite comes with a Carbon aggregator which can do this.

StatsD does not even provide aggregation of the kind I am talking about.

My question is - should I use statsd at all for my use case? Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 34):

1. StatsD operates over UDP, which removes the risk of carbon-aggregator.py being slow to respond and introducing latency in your application. In other words, loose coupling.
2. StatsD supports sampling of inbound metrics, which is useful when you don't want your aggregator to take 100% of all data points to compute descriptive statistics. For high-volume code sections, it is common to use 0.5%-1% sample rates so as to not overload StatsD.
3. StatsD has [broad client-side](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/wiki) support.

Comment: Thanks. Except for #2, all points are valid for Carbon as well. Carbon can be configured to listen on UDP, and it also has wide client support.

Answer (score 32):

**tldr:** you will probably want statsd (or [carbon-c-relay](https://github.com/grobian/carbon-c-relay)) if you ever want to look at the server-specific sums or averages.

**carbon aggregator** is designed to aggregate values from **multiple metrics** together into a single output metric, typically to increase graph rendering performance. **statsd** is designed to aggregate **multiple data points** in a single metric, because otherwise graphite only stores the last value reported in the minimum storage resolution.

**statsd example:**
assume that your graphite storage-schemas.conf file has a minimum retention of 10 seconds (the default) and your application is sending approximately 100 data points every 10 seconds to *services.login.server1.count* with a value of 1.  without statsd, graphite would only store the last count received in each 10-second bucket. after the 100th message is received, the other 99 data points would have been thrown out.  however, if you put statsd between your application and graphite, then it will sum all 100 datapoints together before sending the total to graphite. so, without statsd your graph only indicates *if* a login occurred in during the 10 second interval. with statsd, it indicates *how many* logins occurred in during that interval. ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095998/accumulation-of-value-in-graphite))

**carbon aggregator example:** assume you have 200 different servers reporting 200 separate metrics (*services.login.server1.response.time*, *services.login.server2.response.time*, etcetera). on your operations dashboard you show a graph of the average accross all servers using this graphite query: weightedAverage(services.login.server*.response.time, services.login.server*.response.count, 2). unfortunately, rendering this graph takes 10 seconds. to solve this problem, you can add a carbon aggregator rule to pre-calculate the average across all your servers and store the value in a new metric. now you can update your dashboard to simply pull a single metric  (e.g. *services.login.response.time*). the new metric renders almost instantly.

**side notes:**

1. the aggregation rules in storage-aggregation.conf apply to all storage intervals in storage-schemas.conf *except* the first (smallest) retention period for each retention string. it is possible to use carbon-aggregator to aggregate data points within a metric for that first retention period. unfortunately, aggregation-rules.conf uses "blob" patterns rather than regex patterns. so you need to add a separate aggregation-rules.conf file entry for every path depth and aggregation type. the advantage of statsd is that the client sending the metric can specify the aggregation type rather than encoding it in the metric path. that gives you the flexibility to add a new metric on the fly regardless of metric path depth.  if you wanted to configure carbon-aggregator to do statsd-like aggregation automatically when you add a new metric, your aggregation-rules.conf file would look something like this:

   ```
   <n1>.avg (10)= avg <n1>.avg$
   <n1>.count (10)= sum <n1>.count$
   <n1>.<n2>.avg (10)= avg <n1>.<n2>.avg$
   <n1>.<n2>.count (10)= sum <n1>.<n2>.count$
   <n1>.<n2>.<n3>.avg (10)= avg <n1>.<n2>.<n3>.avg$
   <n1>.<n2>.<n3>.count (10)= sum <n1>.<n2>.<n3>.count$
   ...
   <n1>.<n2>.<n3> ... <n99>.count (10)= sum <n1>.<n2>.<n3> ... <n99>.count$
   ```

   notes: the trailing "$" is not needed in graphite 0.10+ (currently pre-release) [here is the relevant patch on github](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/commit/f80d086073bf549589ee5727241911c60410ac09) and here is the standard documentation on [aggregation rules](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf)
2. the weightedAverage function is new in graphite 0.10, but generally the averageSeries function will give a very similar number as long as your load is evenly balanced. if you have some servers that are both slower and service fewer requests or you are just a stickler for precision, then you can still calculate a weighted average with graphite 0.9. you just need to build a more complex query like this:

   ```
   divideSeries(sumSeries(multiplySeries(a.time,a.count), multiplySeries(b.time,b.count)),sumSeries(a.count, b.count))
   ```
3. if statsd is run on the client box this also reduces network load. although, in theory, you could run carbon-aggregator on the client side too. however, if you use one of the statsd client libraries, you can also use sampling to reduce the load on your application machine's cpu (e.g. creating loopback udp packets). furthermore, statsd can automatically perform multiple different aggregations on a single input metric (sum, mean, min, max, etcetera)
4. if you use statsd on each app server to aggregate response times, and then re-aggregate those values on the graphite server using carbon aggregator, you end up with an average response time weighted by app server rather than request. obviously, this only matters for aggregating using a mean or top_90 aggregation rule, and not min, max or sum. also, it only matters for mean if your load is unbalanced. as an example: assume you have a cluster of 100 servers, and suddenly 1 server is sent 99% of the traffic. consequentially, the response times quadruple on that 1 server, but remain steady on the other 99 servers. if you use client side aggregation, your overall metric would only go up about 3%. but if you do all your aggregation in a single server-side carbon aggregator, then your overall metric would go up by about 300%.
5. [carbon-c-relay](https://github.com/grobian/carbon-c-relay) is essentially a drop-in replacement for carbon-aggregator written in c. it has improved performance and regex-based matching rules. the upshot being that you can do both statsd-style datapoint aggregation and carbon-relay style metric aggregation and other neat stuff like multi-layered aggregation all in the same simple regex-based config file.
6. if you use the [cyanite](http://cyanite.io/) back-end instead of carbon-cache, then cyanite will do the intra-metric averaging for you in memory (as of [version 0.5.1](https://github.com/pyr/cyanite/pull/80)) or at read time (in the version <0.1.3 architecture).

Answer (score 10):

If the Carbon aggregator offers everything you need, there is no reason not to use it. It has two basic aggregation functions (sum and average), and indeed these are not covered by StatsD. (I'm not sure about the history, but maybe the Carbon aggregator already existed and the StatsD authors did not want to duplicate features?) Receiving data via UDP is also supported by Carbon, so the only thing you would miss would be the sampling, which does not matter if you aggregate by averaging.

StatsD supports different metric types by adding extra aggregate values (e.g. for timers: mean, lower, upper and upper Xth percentile, ...). I like them, but if you don't need them, the Carbon aggregator is a good way to go too.

I have been looking at the source code of the Carbon aggregator and StatsD (and [Bucky](https://github.com/cloudant/bucky/), a StatsD implementation in Python), and they are all so simple, that I would not worry about resource usage or performance for either choice.

Comment: Exactly. My question essentially arose from a suspicion that many people might be opting for statsd based on its coolness factor and the fact that many are using it in this configuration. It's a great tool, but given my use case, not required as a middleman.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like carbon aggregator and statsd support disjoint set of features:

- statsd supports rate calculation and summation but does not support averaging values
- carbon aggregator supports averaging but does not support rate calculation.

Answer (score -1):

Because graphite has a minimum resolution, so you cannot save two different values for the same metric during defined interval. StatsD solves this problem by pre-aggregating them, and instead of saying "1 user registered now" and "1 user registered now" it says "2 users registered".

The other reason is performance because:

1. You send data to StatsD via UDP, which is a fire and forget protocol, stateless, much faster
2. StatsD etsy's implementation is in NodeJS which also increases the performance a lot.

Comment: Can you point towards any link which talks about graphite's minimum resolution? For the other points - (1) Carbon also support UDP (https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/216002)  (2) The data will ultimately get into Carbon, so is it relevant if statsd is high performing or not (unless we always use statsd for aggregation and hence Carbon ends up getting less data than it would have if it had been talked to directly)?

Comment: Here you have the requested link: https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md#correlation-with-statsds-flush-interval

Comment: The link you have posted talks about why one should not push data from _statsd_ to graphite faster than every 10 seconds. It does not say that graphite's minimum resolution is 10 seconds. Does graphite's documentation say that?

Comment: -1. In fact, Graphite's minimum resolution is 1 second, not 10 - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19150080

Comment: // , @rogercampos, would you please update this post?