# Graphite/Carbon how to get per-second metrics

Tags: java, apache-storm, metrics, graphite

I've [dockerized graphite](https://github.com/projectvalis/dockerized_graphite) and am working with [this library](https://github.com/verisign/storm-graphite) to get metrics from an Apache Storm topology. I'm getting metrics data, but no matter what I do I can only get data per minute where I really need the points to be per second.

[image]

As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116383/graphite-graph-how-fast-can-we-update-the-graph) I've set the retention policy to grab data every second. I've also set

```
conf.put("topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs", 1);
```

and

```
void initMetrics(TopologyContext context) {
    messageCountMetric = new CountMetric();
    context.registerMetric("digest_count", messageCountMetric, 1);
}
```

in the class that's setting up the topology and the bolt itself, respectively. To my understanding this should cause metrics to be reported every second. What am I missing here? How can I get metrics to be reported every second?

t/y in advance and happy holidays all!

**update 1**

here is my storage-schemas.conf file:

```
root@cdd13a16103a:/etc/carbon# cat storage-schemas.conf 
# Schema definitions for Whisper files. Entries are scanned in order,
# and first match wins. This file is scanned for changes every 60 seconds.
#
#  [name]
#  pattern = regex
#  retentions = timePerPoint:timeToStore, timePerPoint:timeToStore, ...

# Carbon's internal metrics. This entry should match what is specified in
# CARBON_METRIC_PREFIX and CARBON_METRIC_INTERVAL settings
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 1s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y


[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y


[test]
pattern = ^test.
retentions = 1s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y

[storm]
pattern = ^storm.
retentions = 1s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y
```

Here is my config setup:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(false);
conf.put("topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs", 1);
conf.registerMetricsConsumer(GraphiteMetricsConsumer.class, 4);
conf.put("metrics.reporter.name", "com.verisign.storm.metrics.reporters.graphite.GraphiteReporter");
conf.put("metrics.graphite.host", "127.0.0.1");
conf.put("metrics.graphite.port", "2003");
conf.put("metrics.graphite.prefix", "storm.test");
```

Comment: Could you share your current `storage-schemas.conf` and your `storm.yaml`? Have you read https://github.com/verisign/storm-graphite#carbon-configuration? Finally, keep in mind that Graphite will use the smallest granularity compatible (available) with the time range you're showing. For example, if you have `1s:10m,1m:3d` retention and you're showing 1 hour, you will see 1m resolution.

Comment: @dukebody I've posted the additional information you've asked for. I have checked out the information you posted, and several others, but clearly I'm missing something because no matter what I do I'm only getting reports every minute. t/y for your assistance - this has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to apply changes in `storage-schemas.conf` you have to:

- restart carbons
- delete old *.wsp or use `whisper-resize.py` to apply scheme
- restart carbon-cache
- make sure that `DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION` in webapp's local_settings.py is set to 1
- make sure nginx/apache2/uwsgi cache is set up correctly as well, if any

There is more [whisper-* tools shipped with graphite](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper). The next you may be interested is `whisper-info.py`

```
    bash$ whisper-info.py /graphite/whisper/prod/some/metric.wsp 
    maxRetention: 1296000
    xFilesFactor: 0.5
    aggregationMethod: average
    fileSize: 142600

    Archive 0
    retention: 691200
>>  secondsPerPoint: 1
    points: 11520
    size: 138240
    offset: 40

    Archive 1
    retention: 1296000
    secondsPerPoint: 3600
    points: 360
    size: 4320
    offset: 138280
```

Comment: w00t -- I'll give this a go when I get back into work on Mon!

Comment: the issue turned out to be the local-settings.py file. I was updating carbon.conf but I totally forgot about the local_settings file. t/y for your help - this was driving me nuts lol.