# How to set Graphite X axis to show time interval in seconds?

Tags: graphite

I have installed and configured Graphite. I need to show the time interval in X axis in seconds. Below is the configuration I have given in /etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf file.

```
# Schema definitions for Whisper files. Entries are scanned in order,
# and first match wins. This file is scanned for changes every 60 seconds.
#
#  [name]
#  pattern = regex
#  retentions = timePerPoint:timeToStore, timePerPoint:timeToStore, ...

# Carbon's internal metrics. This entry should match what is specified in
# CARBON_METRIC_PREFIX and CARBON_METRIC_INTERVAL settings
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[test]
pattern = ^test\.
retentions = 10s:10m,1m:1h,10m:1d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:30d
```

Though I have given retentions time to be 1s, im still given the below UI where the interval is still in minutes.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT : According to the answer in this question [Graphite/Carbon how to get per-second metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457743/graphite-carbon-how-to-get-per-second-metrics) I tried deleting all the wsp file in carbon and whisper folders, set the dault duration in local_settings.py to 1s and restarted the carbon service. But  nginx/apache2/uwsgi cache is not in there in my installation and so is whisper-info.py. Though I made whatever changes that I could make from this solution, still I'm shown the graph in minute intervals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphite/Carbon how to get per-second metrics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457743/graphite-carbon-how-to-get-per-second-metrics)

Comment: @kwarunek I edited the question with how that question answer doesn't work for me. Please remove the duplicate mark :)